# Why does health checker not work correctly?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I use Kubernetes Engine and all worked fine, but suddenly one of my domain start to show me 502 error. I've checked my app via IP of service (type: LoadBalancer) and all worked fine. I've discovered as a result of research that health checker of loadbalancer(ingress created it) does not think that everything is ok. But as soon as I change something in the health checker itself (protocol or even an interval), everything starts working for a few minutes, and then again starts to give 502 error.
Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Best regards,
Vadim

Comment: Can you share your deployment configuration? At first glance, I would say your one of your containers readinessProbe is too quick to mark your Pod unhealthy - might be the timeout that's too low. Could have worked fine for a while, and with data accumulating in your application, it's slowing down, ... If you look at the events for the Pod receiving traffic for your LoadBalancer Service, you may see those checks failing from time to time.

Comment: Also, could you clarify, ... "health checker of loadbalabcer (ingress created it)". Are you integrating with a cloud provider (GKE, AWS, openstack, ...), if so which one, what's the health check returning with an error (external LB or internal to k8s), does the problem persist when you bypass the LB, querying kubernetes ingresses directly?

Answer (score 0):

As written in the tag I am using GCP) I've checked readinessProbe and have changed values to 60, but it have not helped. But I've tried to change path in health checker and all become work fine. I don't understand why everything worked before and suddenly changed. I hope to find out someday. Thank you SYN!